# How to easily get to the ancestor element that is placed 12 levels up from its descendent?

Tags: javascript

```
<div class="furniture--4 border--round arrows_style owl-carousel owl-theme row mt--50 owl-loaded owl-drag">
  <div class="owl-stage-outer">
    <div class="owl-stage" style="transform: translate3d(-1392px, 0px, 0px); transition: all 0s ease 0s; width: 5568px;">
      <div class="owl-item cloned" style="width: 464px;">
        <div class="product product__style--3">
          <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-12">
            <div class="product__thumb">
              <a class="first__img" href="single-product.html"><img src="images/books/7.jpg" alt="product image"/></a>
              <div class="hot__box"><span class="hot-label">HOT</span></div>
            </div>
            <div class="product__content content--center">
              <h4><a href="single-product.html">Lando</a></h4>
              <ul class="prize d-flex">
                <li>$35.00</li>
                <li class="old_prize">$50.00</li>
              </ul>
              <div class="action">
                <div class="actions_inner">
                  <ul class="add_to_links">
                    <li>
                      <a class="cart" href="#">
                        <i class="bi bi-shopping-bag4"></i>
                      </a>
                    </li>
                  </a>
                </li>
              </ul>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

In the above HTML document I've added a click event for each `bi bi-shopping-bag4` class elements (at the bottom of the document with tag `<i>` ).

What I need is to move 12 levels up from this element with `event.target`. How can I do this easily, to save me having to write "parentElement" 12 times in a row?

Comment: This sounds really brittle, do you **ever** forsee that this component might move in the heirarchy at some point in the future?  Why not use one of the other upwards selectors like `closest()`?  In your example which element actually is the 12th parent from your perspective? It's difficult to count like this.

Comment: could you provide an example with it? the last `div` is the 12th parent

Comment: This is what "Event Delegation" is all about. When an event fires and we capture that event with an event handler, the event object passed to the handler contains a reference to both the _target_ of the event and the element upon which the event handler is listening to. All you have to do is set a single event handler "12 levels up" and you have what you need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be achieved quite easily without jQuery.

Consider the code snippet below - the idea here is to traverse up the DOM (from the first element that matches the "starting selector") and at each step, check to see if that ancestor node matches the "ending selector". For more information on how this works, see the comments in the code snippet below:

```js
/*
Utilitiy function to find ancestor node in DOM with class "ancestorClass"
from first node in DOM with class "startClass"
*/
function findMatchingAncestor(startClass, ancestorClass) {

  /*
  Query dom for node of with startClass. This would be "bi-shopping-bag4"
  in the case of your OP
  */
  let node = document.querySelector(`.${startClass}`);

  /*
  Start iteration to traverse up tree looking for matching ancestors
  */
  while (node) {
 
    /*
    If ancestor node's class list contains "ancestorClass", return this node.
    In the case of your OP, we're looking for the first ancestor with the 
    "owl-stage-outer" class
    */
    if (node.classList.contains(ancestorClass)) {
      return node;
    }

    /*
    If ancestor node didn't contain the "ancestorClass" in class list, 
    traverse up the next level of the DOM
    */
    node = node.parentElement;
  }
}

// Fetch the .bi-shopping-bag4
console.log(findMatchingAncestor('bi-shopping-bag4', 'owl-stage-outer'))
```

```html
<div class="furniture--4 border--round arrows_style owl-carousel owl-theme row mt--50 owl-loaded owl-drag">


  <div class="owl-stage-outer">
    <div class="owl-stage" style="transform: translate3d(-1392px, 0px, 0px); transition: all 0s ease 0s; width: 5568px;">
      <div class="owl-item cloned" style="width: 464px;">
        <div class="product product__style--3">
          <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-12">
            <div class="product__thumb">
              <a class="first__img" href="single-product.html"><img src="images/books/7.jpg" alt="product image"></a>
              <div class="hot__box">
                <span class="hot-label">HOT</span>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="product__content content--center">
              <h4><a href="single-product.html">Lando</a></h4>
              <ul class="prize d-flex">
                <li>$35.00</li>
                <li class="old_prize">$50.00</li>
              </ul>
              <div class="action">
                <div class="actions_inner">
                  <ul class="add_to_links">
                    <li>
                      <a class="cart" href="#">
                        <i class="bi bi-shopping-bag4"></i>
                      </a>
                    </li>
                  </ul>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

All you have to do is find **some** level of uniqueness and target that.

The easiest way of doing this is with **[`.closest()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/closest)**, which is supported in most browsers:

In your example, I assume in the above you're looking to target `.furniture--4`.

Here's a trimmed down example showing how that can be targeted:

```js
document.getElementsByClassName('cart')[0].addEventListener('click', function() {
  const target = this.closest(".furniture--4");
  console.log(target.innerHTML);
});
```

```html
<div class="furniture--4">
  <div>
    <div>
      <span class="cart">Click me</span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Obviously, this will only work when the target element is the closest element with the relevant selector, but you can always target the element **directly** if need be as well.

Here this is shown with **[`document.getElementsByClassName('furniture--4')[0]`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName)**:

```js
document.getElementsByClassName('cart')[0].addEventListener('click', function() {
  const target = document.getElementsByClassName('furniture--4')[0];
  console.log(target.innerHTML);
});
```

```html
<div class="furniture--4">
  <div>
    <div>
      <span class="cart">Click me</span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Randy, `.closest()` may be a jQuery method, but it is also a standard in JavaScript.

Comment: @RandyCasburn Click the link; not only does it show that it's a native DOM method, it also provides a polyfill for non-compliant browsers.

Comment: Whoops...I got ahead of myself.